# Add number to a list and find the biggest number

Tags: prolog

This question is based on a previous question of mine.[Here is the previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491537/count-the-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-string)
So as you can see I'm now able to get the score for every key I put in the question but now I need to find the biggest score and add it with the sum of all the other scores of the documents. For example if I do a query I want the scores to be added in a list. For example
it could look like this `scores[1,2,3,2,1]` then I want to extract the max from this list which is 3 and add it to the sum of the list which is 1+2+3+2+1 = 9.

I can't make it work. Append only works with lists as far as I know. Can I add the `Acc` from

```
score([Tag|Tags], Acc, Count, document(Title,_)) :-
    (   sub_string(case_insensitive, Tag, Title)  % Check for Tag in Title
    ->  Acc1 is Acc + 1                           % Increment acc if found
    ;   Acc1 = Acc                                % Otherwise, no increment
    ),
    score(Tags, Acc1, Count, document(Title,_)).  % Score remaining tags
```

to a list using member? I tried it but I couldn't make it work...

Here is an example:
This is my query

```
?- document(T,_),score([rule],Acc,document(T,_)).
```

and as a result I will get

```
T = 'Rules; Semantic Technology; and Cross-Industry Standards',Acc = 1;
T = 'Rule Transformation and Extraction',Acc = 1;
T = 'Rules and Uncertainty',Acc = 1;
T = 'Rules and Rules',Acc = 2;
```

and so on... I want each of these `Acc` to be added in a list and then I want to extract the `max Acc` of this list.

Comment: see [max_list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=max_list/2)/2

Comment: I've seen it but I can't add Acc into a list first

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to collect the `Acc`s you get from a number of `score` queries? Your question isn't very clear at all on this. And how are you determining what those queries look like? Some concrete examples would be helpful (you've mentioned "example" twice but they aren't concrete). I'd suggest using `findall` to collect all the `Acc` results, but I can't tell from your question what that query would exactly look like.

Comment: @lurker added an exmaple to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

library(aggregate) could be a good starting point, but to put it to good use I think you need to decouple the tasks, and use sub_atom/5 that actually can 'search' multiple occurrences:

```
tags_count(Tags, Title, Count) :-
    downcase_atom(Title, Downcase),
    aggregate_all(count, (member(T,Tags), sub_atom(Downcase, _,_,_, T)), Count).

counters(Tags, L) :-
    findall(C, (document(T,_), tags_count(Tags,T,C)), L).
```

test:

```
document('Rules; Semantic Technology; and Cross-Industry Standards',_).
document('Rule Transformation and Extraction',_).
document('Rules and Uncertainty',_).
document('Rules and Rules',_).

?- counters([rule], L), max_list(L, Max), sum_list(L, Sum), Tot is Sum + Max.
L = [1, 1, 1, 2],
Max = 2,
Sum = 5,
Tot = 7.
```

*edit* Really, all work is done 'inside' aggregate_all/3

```
tags_tot_max_title(Tags, Tot, Max, Title) :-
    aggregate_all(info(sum(C), max(C, T)), (
        document(T, _), tags_count(Tags, T, C)
    ), info(Sum, max(Max, Title))),
    Tot is Sum + Max.
```

yields

```
?- tags_tot_max_title([rule], Tot, Max, Title).
Tot = 7,
Max = 2,
Title = 'Rules and Rules'.
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it show me the Title of the document with the highest score?

Comment: One last thing. What exactly is info? What is it doing?

Comment: @captain: info/2 it's just an arbitrary name for a pair of 'aggregate functions' results. I've chosen the name to be less confusing as possible... You can see that the same name is used as first (input pattern) and last (output pattern) call to aggregate_all/3, that does something really complicated inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following query:

```
document(T,_),score([rule],Acc,document(T,_))
```

And you want to collect results over multiple such queries, and sort them (and assuming unique elements), you can use `setof`:

```
setof(doc(Acc, T), ((document(T, _), score([rule], Acc, document(T, _)), Accs)
```

The list `Accs` will be a collection of pairs `doc(Acc, T)` sorted in ascending order of `Acc`. [*N.B.*, Conveniently, `setof` is smart about sorting lists even when the elements are compound terms. So terms such as `doc(X, Y)` will sort in order of `X` first then `Y` using the `@` comparitors.] If you reverse the list and take the head, you'll get the maximum `Acc` along with the corresponding `T`:

```
reverse(Accs, [doc(MaxAcc, MaxT)|_])
```

You can put that together into a predicate:

```
max_doc_acc(Tags, MaxAcc, Doc) :-
    setof(doc(Acc, T), ((document(T,_), score(Tags, Acc, document(T,_)), Accs),
    reverse(Accs, [doc(MaxAcc, Doc)|_]).
```

And then query something like:

```
max_doc_acc([rule], MaxAcc, Doc).
```

Comment: Does this work? I can't make it work. I think that it has a problem with the way the brackets are positioned. Also how would a query look like? I also fixed the brackets and I can compile it without a problem, but I can't figure out how to make a query. What exactly is Doc?

Comment: @captain `doc` is just a functor I invented for this purpose. It's a nice way of grouping two data items without using a list. I didn't get a chance to test this code mydelf, but it should be roughly right if I understood your code posting correctly. When you say you *fixed the brackets* I don't know what you mean. They all look OK to me.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and I was getting errors, some brackets where missing. I added them and it worked.

Comment: @captain that's cool. When I first posted the answer I did have a typo which I fixed within the few minutes of my initial post. Maybe you grabbed it before I fixed it.